# Getting javascript error for large data in body of mailto function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, mailto

I want to show data stored in Array-list in body of Mailbox. User can then add mail ids in To: according to his/her convenience and send the mail.
But its throwing JavaScript error when large amount of data is sent to body.

Here is the test code of .aspx page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function mail()
             {
                 var array_store;
                 array_store = document.getElementById("array_store");
                 var vs = array_store.value;
                 window.location.href = "mailto: &body=" + encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(vs));
             }
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:Button ID="Button_mail" runat="server" Text="OpenInMailBox" OnClientClick="mail()" />

        <input type="hidden" id="array_store" name = "ArrayStore" value = '<%=this.ArrayStore %>'  />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code of .CS page :

```
public partial class mailto_check : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected System.Text.StringBuilder ArrayStore = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    string str = "";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.Add("Test1");
        al.Add("hello ");
        al.Add("Testing");

        try
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < al.Count; y++)
            {
               str = al[y].ToString();
               this.ArrayStore.Append(str+",%0D");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

for large data I tested it by adding values to array-list.
Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance for positive answers.

Comment: What's the Error message

Comment: I don't understand, do you need a large e-mail body or a large list of TOs? Limit is both from Windows and mail client you're using then if you need a large body text there is no hope to use mailto:

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti the mail body contains the email addresses.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, Thanks for your valuable time.for large data, its showing a popup box with text "Javascript runtime error" on it. Mail body contains values of list. there is no email address added.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, Thanks for looking in this question, I have a large list, And i am sending these list values as string to mail body.For small string, mailto is working but not for large values.If mailto is of no use, please suggest me an alternative. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are pretty low limits on mailto URL length, according to mail client it ranges from 0.5 KB to ~2 KB. Unfortunately I don't have any viable alternative...